# Best practice to join product attributes

Tags: collection, backend, best-practice

I have a custom table with a product reference `product_id`. Now I would like to show product information (sku, name) in my **backend grid**, but I am unsure what is the best practice to do this?

My best guess for `SKU` is as follows:

```
$collection->join(
    'catalog/product',
    'product_id=`catalog/product`.entity_id',
    array('product_sku' => 'sku')
)
```

*(code from the* `_prepareCollection()` *method in my grid block class)*

But what about the product name? It can be found in catalog_product_entity_varchar. My understanding is that you can rather easy get it if your own resource model and collection is based on `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract` because then you can use methods like `joinAttribute`.
But my model is based on a simple table and extending from `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract`and there is no `joinAttribute` method available.

So what is the best way to get the product name in this case?

Thanks for your time and help :-)

**Update:**
To be more precise, I was talking about my resource model and collection. It matches a simple flat table with just a few attributes like

```
entity_id    product_id    created_at    user_id
```

My intention is to grid in the backend where I show some statistics:

```
ProductSku    Count(ProductSku)    MAX(created_at)
```

As far as I know, the best approch to do this, is via the grid block class and the method to go is `_prepareCollection()`.

My method looks like this:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    // Get and set our collection for the grid
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $collection
        ->join(
            'catalog/product',
            'product_id=`catalog/product`.entity_id',
            array('product_sku' => 'sku')
            )
        ->addExpressionFieldToSelect('product_count', 'COUNT({{product_id}})', 'product_id')
        ->addExpressionFieldToSelect('newest', 'MAX({{created_at}})', array('created_at'=>'main_table.created_at'))
        ->getSelect()->group('product_id');
    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

This works well for the sku (which I refer to as product_sku in the `_prepareColums()` method. But what `join` do I need to insert here in order to get the name (and e.g. the manufacturer)?

Am I doing something wrong because I can't use `joinLeft()`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your collection class (`/Some/Module/Model/Mysql4 (or Resource)/YourModel/Collection.php`) add this method:

```
public function addProductData()
    {
        /** add particular attribute code to this array */
        $productAttributes = array('name', 'price', 'url_key');
        foreach ($productAttributes as $attributeCode) {
            $alias     = $attributeCode . '_table';
            $attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
                ->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attributeCode);

            /** Adding eav attribute value */
            $this->getSelect()->join(
                array($alias => $attribute->getBackendTable()),
                "main_table.product_id = $alias.entity_id AND $alias.attribute_id={$attribute->getId()}",
                array($attributeCode => 'value')
            );
            $this->_map['fields'][$attributeCode] = 'value';
        }
        /** adding catalog_product_entity table fields */
        $this->join(
            'catalog/product',
            'product_id=`catalog/product`.entity_id',
            array('sku' => 'sku', 'type_id' => 'type_id')
        );
        $this->_map['fields']['sku']     = 'sku';
        $this->_map['fields']['type_id'] = 'type_id';
        return $this;
    }
```

In your grid block use this function:

```
 protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('some/yourmodel')
            ->getCollection()->addProductData();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

Comment: This looks promising, but it does not work unfortunately. My Collection extends from `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract` and I get an error `Call to undefined method Mycompany_Module_Model_Resource_Mymodel_Collection::joinLeft()`. I guess this is because I don't use an EAV Resource Model?

Comment: Use join instead of joinLeft, I edited the answer

Comment: doh! I feel stupid now! ;-) And I don't know why I tried it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Celldweller, you don't even absolutely need to use `$this->_map['fields']['sku'] = 'sku'` or similar in this case. You need it only if you have several identical fields name and need to do a translation to prevent conflicts. It just adding overhead for this use case. In a different use case, you may use `$this->_map['fields']['my_sku'] = 'sku'` then you can use with the collection and `_prepareColumns`: `$this->addColumn('my_sku', array(…))`, it will help you to prevent conflict for the filtering or columns sorting if you have a field `sku` used in different DB tables common to the collection

Comment: Great answer! It may lead to "item with the same ID already exists" issues though. A simple `$this->getSelect()->group('main_table.product_id');` solves the issue, but maybe the code can be optimised, so that duplicates are not created in the first place?

Comment: When I joined more than one attribute from the product entity and then filtered the grid on one of my joined columns, I got `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'value' in where clause is ambiguous`. I fixed this by changing `$this->_map['fields'][$attributeCode] = 'value';` to `$this->_map['fields'][$attributeCode] = $alias . '.value';`.

Answer (score 4):

Hi Celldweller I hope you're doing well :-)

Maybe you were wrong in your explanation about the class `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract`, you extend a resource collection not the model because you must not extend a model with a collection class if you want to respect the Magento structure. Am I right?

Based on my correction, I see different kind of approach, depending on how often you want to get the product name attribute. In any case, I think to do a sql query via the Magento Framework is the best way and efficient. It's more faster than to do a `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1234)->getName()` for each loaded item. So in fact it will be very similar to the code you use for the `sku`

CODE NOT TESTED

**You want those information each time a collection is loaded**

You may in your collection class set into a `_beforeLoad` method such a code:

```
protected function _beforeLoad()
{
    $productName = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product','name');

    $this->getSelect()
        ->join( array('product_attribute' => $productName->getBackendTable()),
            'main_table.product_id = product_attribute.entity_id',
            array())
        ->where("product_attribute.attribute_id = ?", $productName->getId());
    }

    return parent::_beforeLoad();
}
```

**You want those information ONLY for the grid**

In your `_prepareCollection`, you will have to add a method in your collection with the same code as it was done above into the `_beforeLoad` then you can prepare the collection by using this method. Don't use both, I mean don't use together the same code in `_beforeLoad` and `addProductName` methods, use only one of them. Here is a sample:

Into your `grid.php`:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    ...
    $collection->addProductName();
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Into your Collection.php:

```
public function addProductName()
{
    $productName = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product','name');

    $this->getSelect()
        -> join( array('product_attribute' => $productName->getBackendTable()),
            'main_table.product_id = product_attribute.entity_id',
            array())
        ->where("product_attribute.attribute_id = ?", $productName->getId());

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Great to read you again :-) Thank you very much but I can't use joinLeft() method. I guess it is a EAV resource model-only method? You were right, I was unprecise in my initial question. I will edit it :)

Comment: Oh and btw: Of course I don't want to do a product->load() in such a situation. Shoot me if I ever would dare! ;-) My goal is to have it all in one collection in order to be able to do sorting and filtering in the grid. See the update in my initial post for further details.

Comment: So replace joinLeft by join but you already accepted the other answer although I answered correctly and was the first one to answer :-(

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was so happy that it finally worked, that I didn't think about it. I am very thankful to both of you. Hope you can forgive me! I owe you a beer.

Comment: ahah no worry. We meet you in Berlin with pleasure :-)

Answer (score 4):

I had almost the same problem, but i can't add a comment, because I not have 50 reputation. I spent a lot of time trying to figure out what is wrong (I used code of Sylvain Rayé). My product collection for some reason filtered. So I found a reason.

If you using some import tools (magmi, etc), they often do not create empty attributes at once. Therefore using `->where("product_attribute.attribute_id = ?", $productName->getId())` products that do not have this attribute, will disappear from selection.

Right way is using `joinLeft` like that:

```
$productName = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product','name');

$this->getSelect()
     ->joinLeft(array('product_attribute' => $productName->getBackendTable()),
        "main_table.product_id = product_attribute.entity_id AND
         product_attribute.attribute_id = {$productName->getId()}",
        array());
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -2):

Display custom attribute on product grid.

Please overwrite this block Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid  in your extension and copy functions  _prepareCollection and _prepareColumns into your extension's block file.

Add below code to select attribuet in _prepareCollection function of product grid
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid before    $this->setCollection($collection) line.

```
$attributeCode = 'qc_status';//here your attribute code
        $collection->joinAttribute($attributeCode, 'catalog_product/'.$attributeCode, 'entity_id', null, 'left');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect($attributeCode);
```

And then below code for column in _prepareColumns function of grid.

```
$attributeCodeConfig ='qc_status';//Your attribute code...

        $attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product', $attributeCodeConfig);

        $attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
        $attributeData = $attribute->getData();
        $frontEndLabel = $attributeData['frontend_label'];

        $attributeOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
        $b = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute();
        $attributeOptions2 = array();
        foreach ($attributeOptions as $value) {
            if(!empty($value['value'])) {
                $attributeOptions2[$value['value']] = $value['label'];
            }

        }


        if(count($attributeOptions2) > 0) {
            $this->addColumn($attributeCodeConfig,
                array(
                    'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__($frontEndLabel),
                    'width' => '80px',
                    'index' => $attributeCodeConfig,
                    'type'  => 'options',
                    'options' => $attributeOptions2,

            ));
        } else {
            $this->addColumn($attributeCodeConfig,
                array(
                    'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__($frontEndLabel),
                    'width' => '80px',
                    'index' => $attributeCodeConfig,

            ));
        }
```

Comment: Change core files is no good practice. Same for `new SomeModel()`

Comment: we don't have to changed in core file .we can overwrite that block (Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid ) to accomplish our functionality