# Getting dropdown attribute value when using addAttributeToSelect

Tags: resource-model, dropdown-attribute

When loading a collection how can I get the attribute value text (and not just the option number) when its a dropdown attribute.

Example:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('color'); // color  is a dropdown attribute
```

When using this code the option id's are displaying for `color` such as: 123, 117 etc. and not the text values (like: red, green etc.)

Usually we iterate through each product and get the text for the attribute but since this is being used in the **Catalog->Manage products** page I'm looking for an alternate solution.

Comment: This might be related: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10212/best-practice-to-join-product-attributes

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8164964/925083

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are firstly using `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` and not simply the resource as stated in your question.

Now I am also assuming that you are looping through the results of your collection.

```
foreach($collection as $product) {}
```

Once you have the product object you can call the function `getAttributeText` and specify the attribute code. This will load the attribute get the source and then the option text based on the attribute data assigned to the product.

```
public function getAttributeText($attributeCode)
{
return $this->getResource()
    ->getAttribute($attributeCode)
        ->getSource()
            ->getOptionText($this->getData($attributeCode));
}
```

So if you are looping through your collection you need to simply call:

```
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $color_value = $product->getAttributeText('color');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "_value" after the attribute name like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('color_value'); // color  is a dropdown attribute
```

If you are using flat tables for products, you can look in the catalog_product_flat_1 database table to see the available attributes, I believe.

Comment: This will only work assuming Flat Product tables are enabled.

Comment: Oh, right. I see. backend stuff. Ignore this answer.

Comment: Even with flat tables enabled it doesn't work, this is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to sort by the values? If not, you can select all attribute options as a `$colors` hash with one(!) query and then display them as  `$colors[$product->getColor()]`

Probably it's faster than select each value in the loop or make extra joins, but does not work for collection sorting :(